# $\mathbb{CP}^k$ not retract of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ when $k < n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm currently reading Massey's book on algebraic topology. I do not have a clear understanding on cohomology ring and how it can be applied to prove the claim that $\mathbb{CP}^k$ is not a retraction of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ when $k < n$. Similarly, in the book the same question was asked about quaternion projective space and $\mathbb{RP}^n$. Could someone please explain to me how cohomology ring can be used to derive such results?
Thanks!

Comment: Any special cases you can solve?  Adding this sort of context will improve your Question and make it easier for Readers to respond in a way that helps you (and future readers).

Comment: Hints: In all these cases there cohomology ring is generated by an element of the first non-zero cohomology class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n>k$

The cohomology is $ H^k(\mathbb C P^n)$ is nontrivial iff $k \leq 2n$ and $k$ is even. For a retract, we must let the identity map on $i:\mathbb C P^n\to \mathbb C P^n$ factor through some $f:\mathbb C P^k \to \mathbb C P^n$, where the retraction is given by $r:\mathbb C P^n \to \mathbb CP^k$ in the sense that $:  r \circ f:\mathbb C P^k \to \mathbb C P^k=i$.

But, there is no map $r:\mathbb C P^n \to \mathbb C P^k$ that induces a nontrivial homomorphism $r^*:H^2(\mathbb C P^k) \to  H^2(\mathbb C P^n)$. If $r^*$ were nontrivial, then it would be multiplication by $b \neq 0$, so that $r^*(\alpha_k)=b \cdot\alpha_n$, where $H^*(\mathbb C P^n)=k[\alpha_n]/\alpha_n^{n+1}$.

But $0=r^*(\alpha_k^{k+1})=b^{k+1} \alpha_{n}^{k+1} \neq 0,$

which is absurd.

Comment: Dear Andrea, your proof is not correct because from line 5 on you have falsely assumed that $f:\mathbb C P^n \to \mathbb C P^k$ while in reality the map $f$ goes in the other direction.

Comment: I’m sorry, that was a failure of notation. I meant $r$, which should still work

Comment: Perfect: +1.${}{}$